# How to overcome GCC restriction "could not convert template argument '0' to 'Foo*'"?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Suppose I have code like this:

```
template<class T, T initial_t> class Bar {
  // something
}
```

And then try to use it like this:

```
Bar<Foo*, NULL> foo_and_bar_whatever_it_means_;
```

GCC bails out with error (on the above line):

> could not convert template argument
>   '0' to 'Foo*'

I found this thread: http://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-help/2007-11/msg00066.html, but I have to use NULL in this case (ok, I could probably refactor - but it would not be trivial; any suggestions?). I tried to overcome the problem by creating a variable with value of NULL, but GCC still complains that I pass variable and not address of variable as a template argument. And reference to a variable initialized with default ctor would not be the same as NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rethinking your code is probably the best way to get around it.  The thread you linked to includes a clear quote from the standard indicating that this isn't allowed.

Answer (score 3):

To accept `Bar<Foo, NULL>`, you need

```
template <typename T, int dummy> class Bar; /* Declared but not defined */
template <typename T> class Bar <T,NULL> { /* Specialization */ };
```

since typeof(NULL)==int.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be the same problem as passing a *string literal* as non-type template parameter: it's not allowed. A pointer to an object is allowed as template parameter if the object has **external linkage**: this to guarantee the uniqueness of the type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
Bar<Foo*, (Foo*)NULL> foo_and_bar_whatever_it_means_;
```

?

or reinterpret_cast(0)?

Answer (score 0):

@Dan Olson: there seems to be quite easy workaround.

Create a parent class with only one template parameter. Add a virtual function returning T. For base class it should be hardcoded to be NULL. For deriving class it would return the second template parameter.